# saw+somebody + come

Tags: grammar, meaning

I saw you ***come*** in yesterday.

I saw ***that*** you ***came*** in yestarday.

is there any difference between these sentences in meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **saw** (past tense) something **happen** (base form of verb), you were there and you observed the event directly. **I saw you crash** your car yesterday - I was there at the time and observed the event.

If you **saw** (past tense) **that** something **happened** (past tense), you saw, after the event, a sign, or evidence, that it had happened. **I saw that you crashed** your car yesterday - I saw it wrecked by the side of the road as I passed by.